# Error: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'member'

Tags: python

I'm attempting to add currency commands to my Discord bot using discord.py. This is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.message.member)
    user = ctx.message.member
    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

    em = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance",
                       color=discord.Color.red())
    em.add.field(name="Wallet balance", value=wallet_amt)
    em.add.field(name="Bank balance", value=bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)



@client.command()
async def beg(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.message.member, )

    users = await get_bank_data()

    user = ctx.message.member

    earnings = random.randrange(101)

    await ctx.send(f"Someone gave you {earnings}coins!!")

    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


async def open_account(ctx):
    user = ctx.message.member
    users = await get_bank_data()
    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    return True


async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
        return users
```

But when I use the balance command, I get this error:

Error: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'member'

Answer (score 0):

That is because you need to use `ctx.author` to get the message author.

Comment: When I tried this, I got the error "Error: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'author'"

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because the `message` object in discord.py doesn't have the attribute `member`. Instead, you need to use `message.author`.